# Sorting linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I have a slight problem with sorting in linked lists.
i have a doubly linked list that needs sorting after intital input, the swap function is what i intend to use, but the problem herein lies that it screws up any header pointers there may be. I cannot sort the list by jusr replacing data as there are too many variables and they can change in the course of development (new variables can be added or deleted)

```
task *taskHeader;

struct task{
   task *pprev;
   //large number of variables
   int number;
   task *pnext;
   task(){
     pprev = NULL;
     pnext = NULL;
   }
}
//swap function
void swap(task *task2, task *task3)
   task* task1 = task2->prev; // alias for readability
   task* task4 = task3->next; // alias for readability
   if(task1!=NULL) task1->next = task3;
   task3->prev = task1;
   task3->next = task2;
   task2->prev = task3;
   task2->next = task4;
   if(task4!=NULL) task4->prev = task2;
}

void sort(task *taskHeader){
   task *temp = taskHeader;
   while(temp != NULL){
      if(temp->number < temp->pnext->number) swap(temp, temp->pnext);

   }
}
```

how should i append the swap function to keep my headers intact and not crash when swapping start or end task nodes? currently i do this by adding NULL checks into the swap function to keep the function from going out of bounds and ending up with pointer faults, but is there a better way to solve this?

should i just traverse the linked list back til i reach a point where pprev == NULL and change the header to point towards that node?

Comment: Except of the constructor, this is C, not C++. A bunch of functions, and a global variable storing the head if the list. As I said, C.

Comment: the current code snippet is...but most of the code is in c++ i only used structs to make the linked list, the rest is class based - this is the reason i used a c++ tag as almost everything in c can be compiled within a c++ app

Comment: Nowadays C++ is not a superset of C. Search in SO about this topic. The best example of this: `int new = 0;` Valid C, non-valid C++. **C and C++ are different languages**

Comment: this is only true because "new" is a reserved keyword in c++ and cannot be used as an identifier... a very weak example

Comment: The same code **could have different behaviour in C++ and C**. **If you use C, use C. If you use C++, use C++**. Don't fix them. What you think is *C++ code fully compatible with C* is really **Poor quality C++**. Good C++ avoids globals, raw-pointers, manual-memory-management, etc.

Comment: Other "weak" example: `int main(){}` ***The shortest C++ program ever***. That is not valid C

Comment: Read this please: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/48401/learning-c-properly-not-c-with-classes Seems like was writed for you.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a double linked list , and it is hard to sort.If you want **an orderded list**. maybe you just need write those functions:

A `init` function , only create the head node and store the address to a global variable.

A`insert`  function, which will insert the node to the right  place.

And now , it is ordered ,but you still need other functions to make the list useful.

A `delete` function.

A `find` function

A `size` function.

A `empty` function.

A 'get' function

...

Good luck.

After you command :

insert :

```
   node1 
    ||
   node2
    ||       
   node3
```

If you need insert a new node to the list, just behind node1.

```
 1. create a new node node4             
 2. find the node1                      node1
 2. node1->next->pre = node4             |
 3. node4->next = node1->next    -->     |node4
                                         | ||
                                        node2
                                         ||
                                        node3

 4.node4->pre = node1         
 5.node1->next = node4           -->    node1
                                         ||
                                        node4
                                         ||
                                        node2
                                         ||
                                        node3
```

Comment: the linked list cannot be sorted on insert as the nummeral values are calculated at a point beyond the list creation.... this is why there is a need for a sort/swap function. But if i use insert and delete id have to create a temporary node right? how do i carry over the data and pointers to it?

Comment: @jaanusalnek I give you the mothed of insert a node, hope you can write the code by yourself